# “She gives her mother a flower on mothers day” — How do I say ‘on’?

Tags: word-choice, preposition, time

I want to translate the following sentence:

> She gives her mother a flower on mothers day

At first I wrote

> Sie gibt ihrer Mutter eine Blume auf Muttertag.

But my German friend told me it should be

> Sie gibt ihrer Mutter eine Blume zum Muttertag.

Is *zum* in this context equal to *zu dem*? And how do I know that I should use *zum*? What is the explanation, according to grammatic rules?

Answer (score 3):

In general, there are three ways to express something happening *on* a certain (holi)day:

- Use no preposition

  > Weihnachten fahren wir in den Thüringer Wald.
- Use *an*

  > An Weihnachten fahren wir in den Thüringer Wald.
- Use *zu*

  > Zu Weihnachten fahren wir in den Thüringer Wald.

In case of mother’s day, the word *Muttertag* requires a contracted article for some reason, which makes the null preposition impossible. Note that that is not a general rule: *Fronleichnam* for example does not take one.

> Sie schenkt ihr Blumen am Muttertag.
>
> Sie schenkt ihr Blumen zum Muttertag.

*An* emphasises that the flower present happened on exactly that day, but it might just as well have been ‘Wednesday’ rather than ‘mother’s day. *Zum* emphasises that it was *on the occasion of* mother’s day.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is correct. However, it focuses on *zum Muttertag*, rather than on *eine Blume*. That's usually not what you want as it implies the day is important rather than the gift. So, usually you would say

> Sie gibt ihrer Mutter zum Muttertag eine Blume.

You should nearly almost always use *zum* or *zur*, as *zu dem* and *zu der* sound stilted.

Comment: What would you say is the "dativ objekt" and "akkusativ objekt" in the above sentence?

Comment: The person who receives something is put into dative (**whom?**). The thing which is acted on is put into accusative (**what?**).

Comment: The person receiving is the mother, the thing which is acted on is the flower, I would say. Assuming it's correct, why is it zum and not zur, since it's der Tag?

Comment: Yes. And second question, that's another function of the dative. *Zum Muttertag* is an adverbial of time (**when?**). You have to put that in dative if you want to denote a position in time (almost always). You can put it into genetive (seldom: accusative) if want want to denote a period of time instead. *Das Telefon klingelt **während der Fußballübertragung**.*

Comment: The position in time is mothersday, second sunday in may (if my memory is correct) which I can consider to be at a specific time.

Comment: But when trying to translate, I want to use the word "auf" because in English I have used the word "on". But instead using "zu" is something I would consider meaning "to" hence "She gives her mother a flower to mothersday". Maybe that is just something I need to learn?.

Comment: Ah, no. It depends on what you want to express. You could say ***Während des Muttertags** hat er geschlafen.* to express he was sleeping during the whole day. But it's usual to say ***Den Muttertag über** hat er geschlafen.* That's the accusative denoting a time period. It's a bit more colloquial.

Comment: @Olba12: Prepositions is where languages are most different. Latin has them different from Spanish, French, German, English, though it's the root for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would say: "Sie gibt Ihrer Mutter eine Blume **zu** Muttertag." This might not be grammatically correct German but it's the way it is said - at least in the Region where I live.

Comment: Which region is that? Do you have any references for your claim?